# Colocar somente duas casas decimais em uma função de soma sqlServer

Tags: sql-server

Gostaria de saber como faço para colocar apenas duas casas decimais no campo da soma.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Evite incluir imagens, fica ruim para quem ajuda. Explique sua tabela, mostre a query que já tem, e a dúvida. Assim fica bem melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(valorcobrado),2) FROM vendasservicos
```

Leitura sobre o [ROUND](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo